My webpack is bundling my code very slow in React Express project
I have a monolith app it contains React and express. It bundles every time i change my code and it takes 30second in order to update my changes in the screen. Build time is approximatly 30 to 50 seconds. My webpack config file is like this
//webpack.config.js
import path from 'path';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import AssetsPlugin from 'assets-webpack-plugin';
import TerserPlugin from 'terser-webpack-plugin';
import nodeExternals from 'webpack-node-externals'
import { BundleAnalyzerPlugin } from 'webpack-bundle-analyzer';

import pkg from '../package.json';

const isDebug = !process.argv.includes('--release');
const isVerbose = process.argv.includes('--verbose');
const isAnalyze = process.argv.includes('--analyze') || process.argv.includes('--analyse');


const config = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, '..'),

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../build/public/assets'),
    publicPath: '/assets/',
    pathinfo: isVerbose,
  },
  mode: isDebug ? 'development' : 'production',

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
        ],
        query: {
          // https://github.com/babel/babel-loader#options
          cacheDirectory: isDebug,

          // https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/
          babelrc: false,
          presets: [
            // A Babel preset that can automatically determine the Babel plugins and polyfills
            // https://github.com/babel/babel-preset-env
            ['@babel/preset-env', {
              targets: {
                browsers: pkg.browserslist,
              },
              modules: false,
              useBuiltIns: false,
              debug: false,
            }],
            '@babel/preset-react',
          ],
          plugins: ['react-intl'],
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'isomorphic-style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              importLoaders: 1,
              modules: true,
              localIdentName: isDebug ? '[name]-[local]-[hash:base64:5]' : '[hash:base64:5]',
              minimize: !isDebug,
              discardComments: { removeAll: true },
            }
          },
          'postcss-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.md$/,
        loader: path.resolve(__dirname, './lib/markdown-loader.js'),
      },
      {
        test: /\.txt$/,
        loader: 'raw-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        query: {
          name: isDebug ? '[path][name].[ext]?[hash:8]' : '[hash:8].[ext]',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        query: {
          name: isDebug ? '[path][name].[ext]?[hash:8]' : '[hash:8].[ext]',
          limit: 10000,
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(graphql|gql)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'graphql-tag/loader',
      },
    ],
  },

  // Don't attempt to continue if there are any errors.
  bail: !isDebug,

  cache: isDebug,

  stats: {
    colors: true,
    reasons: isDebug,
    hash: isVerbose,
    version: isVerbose,
    timings: true,
    chunks: isVerbose,
    chunkModules: isVerbose,
    cached: isVerbose,
    cachedAssets: isVerbose,
    warnings: isDebug
  },
};

const clientConfig = {
  ...config,

  name: 'client',
  target: 'web',

  entry: {
    client: ['babel-polyfill', './src/clientLoader.js'],
  },
  optimization: {
    ...(isDebug ? {} : {
      minimize: true,
      minimizer: [new TerserPlugin({
        terserOptions: {
          mangle: {
            reserved: ['Td', 'Tr', 'Th', 'Thead', 'Table'],
          },
        },
      })],
    }),
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'async',
      minSize: 30000,
      maxSize: 0,
      minChunks: 1,
      maxAsyncRequests: 5,
      maxInitialRequests: 3,
      automaticNameDelimiter: '~',
      automaticNameMaxLength: 30,
      name: true,
      cacheGroups: {
        vendors: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          priority: -10
        },
        default: {
          minChunks: 2,
          priority: -20,
          reuseExistingChunk: true
        }
      }
    }
  },
  output: {
    ...config.output,
    filename: isDebug ? '[name].js' : '[name].[chunkhash:8].js',
    chunkFilename: isDebug ? '[name].chunk.js' : '[name].[chunkhash:8].chunk.js',
  },

  plugins: [
    // Define free variables
    // https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#defineplugin
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': isDebug ? '"development"' : '"production"',
      'process.env.BROWSER': true,
      __DEV__: isDebug,
    }),

    new AssetsPlugin({
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../build'),
      filename: 'assets.json',
      prettyPrint: true,
    }),

    ...isAnalyze ? [new BundleAnalyzerPlugin()] : [],
  ],

  devtool: isDebug ? 'cheap-module-source-map' : false,

  node: {
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty',
  },
};
 
export default clientConfig;

and my bundler file is like this
//build.js

import cp from 'child_process';
import run from './run';
import clean from './devClean';
import copy from './copy';
import bundle from './bundle';
import render from './render';
import pkg from '../package.json';


async function build() {
  await run(clean);
  await run(copy);
  await run(bundle);

  if (process.argv.includes('--static')) {
    await run(render);
  }

  if (process.argv.includes('--docker')) {
    cp.spawnSync('docker', ['build', '-t', pkg.name, '.'], { stdio: 'inherit' });
  }
}

export default build;

I use
npm run dev
in order to run my code in development mode
My package.json is like this:
{
  "name": "rentall",
  "version": "3.4.2",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10",
    "npm": ">=5.10"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">1%",
    "last 4 versions",
    "Firefox ESR",
    "not ie < 9"
  ],
 
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha \"src/**/*.test.js\" --require @babel/register --require test/setup.js",
    "test:watch": "yarn run test -- --reporter min --watch",
    "clean": "babel-node tools/run clean",
    "copy": "babel-node tools/run copy",
    "extractMessages": "babel-node tools/run extractMessages",
    "bundle": "babel-node tools/run bundle",
    "build": "babel-node tools/run build --openssl-legacy-provider --inspect --max_old_space_size=4096",
    "build:stats": "yarn run build -- --release --analyse",
    "deploy": "babel-node tools/run deploy",
    "render": "babel-node tools/run render",
    "serve": "babel-node tools/run runServer",
    "start": "babel-node tools/run --openssl-legacy-provider --inspect start",
    "devBuild": "babel-node tools/run devBuild --openssl-legacy-provider --inspect --max_old_space_size=4096",
    "dev": "nodemon --exec 'npm run devBuild && npm run serve' --config nodemon.json"
  }
}


I tried to update my webpack to version 5 but it is too complex that's why i couldn't run my bundler in v5. then i saw the article that v5 is 30% slower than v4 in webpack

You can try setting devtool from cheap-module-source-map to eval.
The devtool config defines style of source mapping to enhance the debugging process and this values can affect build and rebuild speed dramatically. eval value is the recommended choice for development builds with maximum performance. This should improve your build time.
devtool: isDebug ? 'eval' : false,


Idon't think it's not that simple
